# How to display block the last part of flex?

Tags: html, css, reactstrap

Let me make the reactstrap a sample. What if want to add a hint text after an input. How could I prevent the p tag to be in an inline format?

[image]

What if, I have Input Group and have a

```
<p class="text-muted mb-0" style="
    display: block;
">アエイオウ</p>
```

at the last part. How can I make it the p tag to get into a new line?
Like this:

[image]

```css
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}
.input-group-prepend, .input-group-append {
    display: flex;
}
.input-group > .input-group-prepend > .input-group-text {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group-text {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.input-group > .form-control {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 1%;
    min-width: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">@</span></div><input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control"><p class="text-muted mb-0" style="
    display: block;
">アエイオウ</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `<p>` out of `.input-group` class.

By doing this, `<p>` will have a full width by default.

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group-prepend,
.input-group-append {
  display: flex;
}

.input-group>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.input-group-text {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.input-group>.form-control {
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 1%;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
</div>

<!-- take the p tag out of input-group -->
<p class="text-muted mb-0 small">アエイオウ</p>
```

**Edit:**

If you cannot change the HTML and you **have to** use CSS, you can also do that by using `flex-basis` on the p element.

Like so -

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group-prepend,
.input-group-append {
  display: flex;
}

.input-group>.input-group-prepend>.input-group-text {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.input-group-text {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.input-group>.form-control {
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 1%;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}


.text-muted {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
  
  <p class="text-muted mb-0 small">アエイオウ</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the p tag cant be taken out? Is there no way to fix it?

Comment: Yes there is. You can use `flex-basis` on the p tag. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xj3fh4bk/6/

Your html code should be like this:

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
</div>
<p class="text-muted mb-0" style="display: block;">アエイオウ</p>
```

Since `.input-group` has display property of `flex`, its children will always align in a row. So, you should take `p` tag outside of `.input-group`

Comment: What if the p tag cant be taken out? Is there no way to fix it?

Comment: As @Debsmita Paul said, you can apply `flex-basis` to it.